# Shortcut of File>Page Style>No Style in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a question. I would like to know what shortcut can I use for File>Page Style>No Style command in Mozilla Firefox, without using any addon. Thanks!

Comment: What version are you using? Have you tried Alt+V, Y, N?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio That comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the OP version, but on Firefox versions 85 and 86, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd> as shortcut for View -> Page Style -> No Style. Note that it's View (not File).